# Create a pipe file in windows/.net

Tags: c#, windows, named-pipes

I am using an older program that generates it's output into a file. I can specify on the command line the file to use, but it must go to a file (no option to send to `stdout`).

I would like to stream that output as it is generated (not wait until the file is finished). In *nix, I would create a named pipe, and use that "file" as the output.

Can this (or something similar) be done in Windows? Can it be done in pure C#, or only c/c++/pInvoke? Is there some library that can do this cross platform?

Answer (score 0):

From your .Net application, you can spawn the legacy application as a [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx), for which you can define, among other things, its [standard output stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx). You can use a file stream or any other kind of stream to redirect the process's output.

Comment: The problem is that the application always sends it's output to a file, not the standard output.

Comment: Oh, I completely misunderstood. Sorry for that, now I get what you really meant.